# How can I run sub-minute cron jobs?

Tags: cron

I would like to run a cron job every Wednesday at 10:31:10, but I just learned that crontab cannot run sub-minute jobs, so the closest I can get is 10:31 a.m. with the below code:

```
31 10 * * WED /file/to/run.py
```

Is it possible to hack around this, or are there other alternatives to cron that could do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to sleep for 10 seconds:

```
# .----------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |   .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |   |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |   |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |   |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |   |  |  |  |
# *   *  *  *  *     command to be executed 
  31 10  *  *  3     sleep 10 && /file/to/run.py
```

Comment: Since my crontab looks like `31 10 * * WED /usr/local/bin/python3 /file/to/run.py`, would `31 10 * * WED sleep 10 && /usr/local/bin/python3 /file/to/run.py` work?

Comment: @Nan yes. The command you execute is of the type `cmd1 && cmd2` which states that `cmd2` is executed if and only if `cmd1` exits successfully. In your example, `cmd1` is `sleep 10` and `cmd2` is your python call. Try it with `cmd2` given by `date > ~/cronoutput.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Cron has a 60 sec granularity.

You can though build a SH script that sleeps for ten seconds and then does X, set your cron job to run a script at 10:31 AM on a wednesday that then sleeps for 10 seconds, then do x.